# Update specific object property value in an array of objects while using inline function

Tags: javascript

My goal is to update the `price` field for an individual object.

Here is my `selectedCurrenciesArray`:

```js
const [selectedSwapCurrencies, setSelectedSwapCurrencies] = useState([
     {
       symbol: null,
       logo: null,
       price: 0
     },
     {
       symbol: null,
       logo: null,
       price: 0
     },
  
  ]);
```

I'm mapping through an `Input` component like so...

```
 {Object.values(selectedSwapCurrencies).map((currency, index) => {

return (
 <Input
     onChange={(e) => setSelectedSwapCurrencies({
               ...selectedSwapCurrencies,
               [selectedSwapCurrencies[index].price]: e.target.value,
                        })


/>
)
})}
```

However, each time I update the input, it deletes the first object in the array entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested)

```js
selectedSwapCurrencies.map((currncy,index)=>{
    return (
 <Input
     onChange={(e) => setSelectedSwapCurrencies({
               ...selectedSwapCurrencies,
               [selectedSwapCurrencies[index].price]: e.target.value,
                        })


/>
)
})
```